# using jQuery chosen in dynamic form fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

This is a Table Row. and it contain 5 input fields. first one is a select box. i'm using chosen jquery plugin to search select items on this. 
This is a dynamic form so i'm duplicating these rows. 
my problem it only works on first row. when i dynamically add a new row select drop down not working. please help!

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control itemId" id="item_id" required="required" name="item_id[]">
            <option value="">Select an item</option>
            <option value="1">Item1</option>
            <option value="2">Item2</option>
            <option value="3">Item3</option>
            <option value="4">Item4</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control item_description" id="item_description" placeholder="Not Required | Optional" name="item_description[]" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Add Number" id="units" required="required" name="units[]" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Add Rate" id="rate" required="required" name="rate[]" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control amount" id="amount" placeholder="Add Hrs and Rate" name="amount[]" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
```

**actual form is in laravel. here is the laravel form code.**

```
<tr>
    <td>
        {!! Form::select('item_id[]', ['' => 'Select an item'] + $items, null, ['class' => 'form-control itemId', 'id' => 'item_id', 'required']) !!}
    </td>
    <td>
        {!! Form::text('item_description[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control item_description', 'id' => 'item_description', 'placeholder' => 'Not Required | Optional']) !!}
    </td>
    <td>
        {!! Form::text('units[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Add Number', 'id' => 'units', 'required']) !!}
    </td>
    <td>
        {!! Form::text('rate[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Add Rate', 'id' => 'rate', 'required']) !!}
    </td>
    <td>
        {!! Form::text('amount[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control amount', 'id' => 'amount', 'placeholder' => 'Add Hrs and Rate']) !!}
    </td>
</tr>
```

**following jQuery code used to populate rows dynamically.**

```
var i = 1;
$("#addRow").click(function() {
    $("table tr:last").clone().find(":input").each(function() {
        $("#item_id" + i).val('').trigger("liszt:updated");
        $(this).val('').attr('id', function(_, id) { return id + i });
    }).end().appendTo("table");
    i++;
});
```

**chosen code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#item_id').chosen();
});
```

Comment: use `.on('click',function(){`  instead of `.click(function(){`

`click()` doesnt work on dynamically created elements... after `live()` was depreciated we use `on()`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Chosen plugin, but you might want to re-initialize it after you change the DOM (i.e., trigger `$('#item_id').chosen();` at the end of the #addRow click handler function).

Comment: Which element do you really want to add chosen to? `$(this)` or `$("#item_id" + i)`?

Comment: `$(this)` has all the input fields in it. i want it only on first select box. so it will be `$("#item_id" + i)`

Answer (score -1):

```
var i = 1;
$("#addRow").click(function() {
    var $row = $("table tr:last").clone().find(":input").each(function() {
        $("#item_id" + i).val('').trigger("liszt:updated");
        $(this).val('').attr('id', function(_, id) { return id + i });
    }).end();
    $row.appendTo("table");
    $row.find("select").chosen();
    i++;
});
```

Comment: `$(this)` contain all the input fields. there are 5 of them. how do i get select drop down box from `$(this)`

Comment: no, i just kept it behind to finish later. in your answer  `$row.find("select").chosen();` should work. i think the problem is jQuery chosen plugin doesn't support when same data duplicated. thank you for your answer. if you have any better idea to do this please share.